# New to linux, github, and homebrew. I want to delete git. How do I do that?

Tags: git, macos, uninstallation

I am very new to Linux command line interface, github, and homebrew. I am on a Mac with OSX.

I would like to remove `git` from my Mac, totally and completely. (I am doing this because I am starting anew, from fresh. My friend installed it for me a while back but I want to go through the process myself).

He installed it via homebrew, I THINK.

Anyway, how exactly do I remove `git`from my Mac safely? Once I remove it, I will go back and re-install it.

Comment: @Mat I know its a website. But I want to remove all [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tyxx4x8u3bpbo8a/Screenshot%202014-05-25%2012.30.55.png) git related stuff from my machine.

Comment: @Mat Also see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/353299/cant-seem-to-uninstall-git), people try to remove git from their machines. Yes, what I mean is command shell sorry, not linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove git assuming it was installed with homebrew

```
brew uninstall git
```

to reinstall:

```
brew install git
```

As Mat mentioned, github is a website, git is a repository.

Comment: You may need to prefix these commands with `sudo`. Try without it first.

Comment: Ok, let me try that! Actually, is there a way I can check how it was installed? Also, can I write that command anywhere on the command line, from any directory?

Comment: You can run it from any directory. If you want to see whether homebrew installed git, try running `brew list` and check if `git` is in the printed list.

Comment: Ok...that seems to have worked... is... is that it?... I guess what confuses me, is when I set up git on my machine, and start to 'push' or 'pull' to and from gitHUB, how does the git in my machine 'know' to sync with github?... Does that make sense? What I mean is, do you need git on local machine to use gitHUB? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes it is that simple to install/uninstall :). To answer your question about where does git know to connect to, the answer is there is a hidden directory in the root of your project `.git`. Inside that directory there is a file `config` which git looks up everytime you do a push or pull to figure out what server (in your case github) to connect to.

Comment: Ohh I see... so now that I have installed git, then I can use it anywhere on my CMI? I am googling how to use it. I guess its just a simple command that you run normally now... BTW, the homebrew FAQ doesnt tell me, but how do you find out what you can or cant install via homebrew? I cant seem to find a list like this anywhere...

Comment: Search homebrew packages: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33354/how-to-know-what-packages-are-available-with-homebrew

Comment: Yes git is a command-line application. It's very useful to become well acquainted with it. You can also supplement it with git-cola, which is has a very nice GUI for staging/commiting code.